# Elementary introduction to creating BibTeX styles?

Tags: bibtex

Are there any good introductory references for the syntax to create a BibTeX style (.bst) file, whose ease of reading is closer to an introductory text for a programming language than to a formal specification document for a programming language?

Obviously, as modifying bibliography styles is an advanced topic for a single facet of the TeX ecosystem, there's not going to be the same kind of pedagogical literature on the subject as *e.g.* for LaTeX. But I'm hoping for something that would allow me to grok, and write, a style file after an hour or two of reading rather than after a day or two of study.

Comment: I particularly like this document: http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~markey/BibTeX/doc/ttb_en.pdf

Comment: Do you want to write from scratch (hard) or only modify existing styles?

Comment: @Corentin Perhaps better to give a 'canonical' link: http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast

Comment: @JosephWright: it is *probable* that I can do what I want by modifying existing styles, but if a good introductory reference can let me see what is possible from scratch, my notion of what I'd like to achieve may expand to meet the boundaries of the feasible.

Comment: @JosephWright I agree, it is probably better to use the ctan link; I was pointing directly to the author's personal page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The document by Nicolas Markey [Tame the BeaST](http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast) is a very good reference. It contains a general presentation of BibTeX, and chapter 4 is devoted to editing `.bst` files. The overall structure of a `.bst` file is explained, as well as the Reverse Polish Notation used by bibtex, and the main functions are described. As far as I'm concerned, I've always found it very helpful.

Otherwise there is also [Designing BibTeX files](https://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/software/tex/btxhak.pdf), by Oren Patashnik, the author of BibTeX (I don't know if there is a "canonical" link to this pdf, if so please feel free to edit my answer).

Answer (score 5):

there should be some documentation in your local TeX installation:

```
$TEXMFDIST/doc/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf
$TEXMFDIST/doc/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf
$TEXMFDIST/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf
```

and if you are familiar with german:

https://archive.org/details/pdfy-DTVSHmzsr3tqPmMh, which is an archived version of the document formerly at http://archiv.dante.de/dante/events/dante2002/handouts/raichle-bibtexprog.pdf

Comment: The German document no longer seems to live at that address. Does anybody know where (if anywhere) it might still be available?