# bibliography style file for Audio Engineering Society (AES) convention

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

EDITED:

Is there a bibliography style file for Audio Engineering Society (AES) conventions (like a .dtx or a .bst file or something)? Or alternatively, is there a way I can create my own that takes my .bib file and formats, for example, a conference entry as shown below?

Author, "Title," presented at the AES 114th convention, Amsterdam, The Netherlands, 2003 March 22--25.

For example, I have a .bib file with a number of entries. When I use the American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics (AIAA) conference template package, they provide the necessary files which allow me to use \bibliographystyle{aiaa} and this automatically formats the entries in the .bib file as the conference requires it to be. I want to know if anyone knows of a similar file for AES conferences or if there isn't one, is there a tutorial where I can learn to create my own file that controls how my bibliography is formatted.

I want to use the same .bib file I have for different conferences and have a file (I think the needed file is a .dtx file or a .bst file) that indicates how the bibliography is formatted in the final latex document.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell what AES is?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I'm a bit confused by the question. Is it just chance that the example you give also concerns AES? It will help if you can post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Can you delete other people's answers?

Comment: @cfr I can vote to delete them (I've already done it).

Comment: `biblatex`/`biber` gives you a lot more flexibility in this regard if that's an option.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Good! I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: You can (probably) do `tex makebst` and follow the prompts to create a bst suited to your needs.  It may produce what you need, but it won't work for really complicated needs.  (For that `biblatex`/`biber` really is better.)

Comment: @jon Thanks! I think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! I think biblatex is what I was looking for. I didn't know about it till now.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title and your question are unclear and misleading.

You assume everybody knows what AES means. My first thought was Advanced Encryption Standard. As you mentioned year and place I infered you mean the Audio Engineering Society.

Are you searching the bib-style for a paper on this conference's proceedings? => [author guidelines including a LaTeX Template and guidelines for the bibliography](http://www.aes.org/journal/authors/guidelines/).

Do you want to know "How to quote talks at a conference?". In this case see [here (without proceedings)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/what-is-the-proper-way-to-represent-a-talk-at-a-conference-with-no-proceedings/18195#18195) or use `inproceedings`.

See here for modifing/creating a bibtex-style: [Elementary introduction to creating BibTeX styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71372/elementary-introduction-to-creating-bibtex-styles)

Comment: Sorry. I had originally posted my question in another forum and lost some information when copying it over here. I have edited my question. Hopefully now it's more clear.

Comment: A commenter above suggested biblatex which I didn't know about until now. But I think that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Shoul have mentioned it: biblatex is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to generate custom styles is with the new [Bibulous program](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/), developed as a replacement for BibTeX. Using the OP's suggested style, one can use a Bibulous style template of the following form (the code below shows the *entire* style file):

```
TEMPLATES:
inproceedings = <au>, \enquote{<title>,} presented at <booktitle>, <address>, <year> <month> <day>.
```

Here the template assumes that the `*.bib` file entries each are of type `inproceedings` and that each of the `<...>` variables are required to be defined inside the entry. Of course, this style file will only allow `inproceedings` entry types. To be able to use other entry types as well, the use would need to define another template for each corresponding type (i.e. a line with `article = ...`, another line with `book = ...` etc.).