# In apsrmp4-1long.bst file, how to add period in the last of the each reference?

Tags: bibtex

Can someone help me to add period in [apsrmp4-1long.bst](http://mydailynote.googlecode.com/svn/notes/apsrmp4-1long.bst):

> Zhang, Z., and G. Huang, 2011, “Micro-and nano-carrier mediated intra-articular drug delivery systems for the treatment of osteoarthritis,” Journal of Nanotechnology 2012, 1–11

The result should be look like this:

> Zhang, Z., and G. Huang, 2011, “Micro-and nano-carrier mediated intra-articular drug delivery systems for the treatment of osteoarthritis,” Journal of Nanotechnology 2012, **1–11.**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Have you had a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-or-personalize-bst-files and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71372/elementary-introduction-to-creating-bibtex-styles ?  They should get you on track to do such a change.

Comment: This seems isolated with to the last bibliography item. Add `\let\oldendthebibliography\endthebibliography \def\endthebibliography{\unskip.\oldendthebibliography}` to the preamble and give some feedback...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, it is not working in my case. I have found the solution. In bst file, i have added "."  at some particular places.