# changing references format

Tags: bibliographies

I have prepared a manuscript in which I put references in a separate file named "sample.bib". In that file the references are written as

```
@article{kastner1992single,
title={The single-electron transistor},
author={Kastner, Marc A},
journal={Reviews of Modern Physics},
volume={64},
number={3},
pages={849},
year={1992},
publisher={APS}
}
@article{flambaum1997distribution,
title={Distribution of occupation numbers in finite Fermi systemsand role of interaction in chaos and thermalization},
author={Flambaum, VV and Izrailev, FM},
journal={Physical Review E},
volume={55},
number={1},
pages={R13},
year={1997},
 publisher={APS}
}
```

and read these references by command: `\bibliography{sample}`

But for submitting the manuscript, journal has recommended to put the references in the body of manuscript. Unfortunately I could not directly put references in the body because by viewing other manuscript with this property I have understood that references in them has been written in the format (for example:)

```
\bibitem{London1938} F. London, Phys. Rev. \textbf{54}, 947 (1938).

\bibitem{Osborne1949} M.F.M. Osborne, Phys. Rev. \textbf{76}, 396 (1949).
```

What I deduced is I have to change all of references in a format which be able to be put in the body manuscript!

Changing all references will take a huge time. Is there a way to reach to this aim in a shorter time or is there any way to automatically change the format of references or other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Compile as usual.  Then you get an file `*.bbl`. Copy the content into your submitted file at the place where you called `\bibliography{sample}` ...  They should have a description what to do exactly for submitting ...  Or add a compilable short code to your answer that we can play with it ...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your guidance, I can see the *.bbl file. but there is a bit problem. I am trying to solve that, Thank you in advance if let me ask about that if I cannot solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let us start with an MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{kastner1992single,
  title     = {The single-electron transistor},
  author    = {Kastner, Marc A},
  journal   = {Reviews of Modern Physics},
  volume    = {64},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {849},
  year      = {1992},
  publisher = {APS},
}
@article{flambaum1997distribution,
  title     ={Distribution of occupation numbers in finite Fermi 
              systemsand role of interaction in chaos and thermalization},
  author    ={Flambaum, VV and Izrailev, FM},
  journal   ={Physical Review E},
  volume    ={55},
  number    ={1},
  pages     ={R13},
  year      ={1997},
  publisher = {APS},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

That result in the following `bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\bibitem{kastner1992single}
Marc~A Kastner.
\newblock The single-electron transistor.
\newblock {\em Reviews of Modern Physics}, 64(3):849, 1992.

\bibitem{flambaum1997distribution}
VV~Flambaum and FM~Izrailev.
\newblock Distribution of occupation numbers in finite fermi systemsand role of
  interaction in chaos and thermalization.
\newblock {\em Physical Review E}, 55(1):R13, 1997.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Now copy this `bbl` file into the TeX code as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % <==============================================
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\bibitem{kastner1992single}
Marc~A Kastner.
\newblock The single-electron transistor.
\newblock {\em Reviews of Modern Physics}, 64(3):849, 1992.

\bibitem{flambaum1997distribution}
VV~Flambaum and FM~Izrailev.
\newblock Distribution of occupation numbers in finite fermi systemsand role of
  interaction in chaos and thermalization.
\newblock {\em Physical Review E}, 55(1):R13, 1997.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

with the result after compiling:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried your answer. It is ok. Just my kept problem was related to this case: a year must be in parentheses (2007), for example and the title of each referred paper had to be removed! I manually corrected them. (I removed titles and put each year in one parenthes)

Comment: @Irreversible, that is a matter of bibliography style --- http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25007/bibtex-defining-own-styles and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71372/elementary-introduction-to-creating-bibtex-styles